# Next 13 does not show Head elements

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I upgraded to next13. The directory structure I have is:

pages/post/[id.jsx]

The Head is coded within the file and used to work is as follows:

```
    return <>
<Head><title>{post.title.substring(0, 40)}</title>
<meta name="description" content={post.title} />
<link rel="canonical" href={process.env.WEB_URI} />
    
    </Head>
    
    ...
```

Nothing shows up in view source under . It used to before I upgraded to next 13. Is this expected behavior and do I need to add a special Head.js file? I am still using the pages directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is - all tags to be used in `<Head>` are needed to be added to **pages/_document.js or _app.js first**.

I used `pageProps.title` in `_app.js` and in the pages such as `/post/[id]` I passed `title:"my title"` in `getServersideProps`.

Hope this helps others.

In app.js add

```
<meta property="og:title" content={pageProps?.title} />
```

In post/[id].js
pass the value as below (the title passed here will be available to app.js as `pageProps.title`:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  ..
  let post = await getPost(db, context.req, context.params.id);
  if (!post) (post={isEmpty: true});
  ..
  return {
    props: {
      post,
      ..
      title: post.title,
```

Answer (score -1):

When using the pages directory `Head` should still work. Are you using `import Head from 'next/head'`? Here is the [upgrade guide](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/upgrade-guide#step-3-migrating-nexthead).

Comment: Without the Head import, there would be errors when using `Head`

Comment: Right, I was thinking maybe you got it from `import { Head } from 'next/document'`, however that should also still work...